# Extending PageFactory annotation to support wait4element(By)?

Tags: java, selenium, annotations, pageobjects, page-factory

Is there a way to extend Selenium Page model with dynamic waits implemented as another annotation. ..

I have wait4element() implemented, I just want to add it as another annotation, similar to @FindBy .

How do I do that ?

Comment: Are you familiar with `Java Reflection API`? I wrote a few libraries that do something like this. You can contact me on Skype because it's a broad topic (see my profile)

Comment: Basically you'll need to define your own `@LazyFindBy` API, and define your own PageFactory class to initialize them.

Answer (score 1):

Metalloid Expected Conditions library contains a similar solution.

You can annotate the element with `@ExpectedCondition` specifying the timeout and condition like this:

```
@ExpectedCondition(timeout = 10, condition = Visibility.class)
@FindBy(id = "login-button")
private WebElement loginButton;
```

In the constructor you have to invoke method responsible for evaluating the elements:

```
public PageObject() {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    ConditionEvaluator.evaluate(driver, this);
}
```

`ConditionEvaluator` collects all elements annotated with `@ExpectedCondition`, creates internally instance of `WebDriverWait` and evaluates the condition provided in `@ExpectedCondition`. It does it immediately. **There is no lazy-instantiation**.

Metalloid contains built-in `Visibility.class` which looks like this:

```
public class Visibility extends Condition {

    public Visibility(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
        super(driver, element);
    }

    @Override
    public ExpectedCondition<?> getExpectedCondition() {
        return ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element);
    }
}
```

The constructor is called with `Java Reflection API` and you don't have to worry about it.

The method `getExpectedCondition` tells Metalloid how to evaluate the condition.

If you want to create your own conditions, simply extend the `Condition` class just like `Visibility.class` does.

This library is a part of Metalloid: https://github.com/Rafal-Laskowski/Metalloid-Core
But can be as well used as stand-alone, just like I described. Wiki: https://github.com/Rafal-Laskowski/Metalloid-Expected-Conditions/wiki